# How to use AdWhirl with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-simpledb, adwhirl

Does anyone know any open source project or adapter for MySQL-AdWhirl? We try to migrate our adwhirl database from Simple-DB to local MySQL server. Does anyone has any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any open source project or adapter for migrating adwhirl database from Simple-DB to local MySQL server currently (according to me). This issue is present from 6-7 months. Still there is no solution for it now.

Hopes somebody will develop it.